# Special characters from an object - using Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, special-characters

I have this array of objects:

```
[{
  "flats":"600m <sup>2</sup>"
}]
```

When I'm getting this object I want to use it like this:

```
{{house.flats}}
```

The result is literally the same as in the object. I was trying the following:

```
<sup>2</sup> 
&#178 
&sup2;
```

but the result is always the same.
Do you know how to get a nice "to power" character?

Comment: I am sorry, but that topic above didnt help me, when i use ng-bind-html with all this resources there is no result at all

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sry - guy above was right - ng-bind-html is an answer.